# Confusion Between 'sample' and 'rbinom' in R

Tags: r, statistics

Why are these not equivalent?

```
#First generate 10 numbers between 0 and .5
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10, 0, .5)
```

These are the two statements I'm confused by:

```
#First    
sample(rep(c(0,1), length(x)), size = 10, prob = c(rbind(1-x,x)), replace = F)
#Second
rbinom(length(x), size = 1, prob=x)
```

I was originally trying to use 'sample'. What I thought I was doing was generating ten (0,1) pairs, then assigning the probability that each would return either a 0 or a 1.

The second one works and gives me the output I need (trying to run a sim). So I've been able to solve my problem. I'm just curious as to what's going on under the hood with 'sample' so that I can understand R better.

Comment: You can execute individual pieces of that line and see what is going on. rep(c(0,1), length(x)) generates a length 20 numeric vector with equal zeroes and ones. c(rbind(1-x,x)) generates a length 20 numeric weights to be used for sampling. Then, the sample itself is going sample one item out of the length 20 vector you supplied.

Comment: For your case there, an equivalent result (less efficient) could be found with `set.seed(1); rbinom(length(x), size = 1, prob=x); set.seed(1); sapply(x, function(xx) sample(0:1, 1, prob=c(1-xx, xx)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first area of difference is the location of the length of the vector specification in the parameter list. The names `size` have different meanings in these two functions. (I hadn't thought about that source of confusion before, and I'm sure I have made this error myself many times.)

The random number generators (starting with `r` and having a distribution suffix) have that choice as the first parameter, whereas `sample` has it as the second parameter. So the length of the second one is 10 and the length of the first is 1. In sample the draw is from the values in the first argument, while 'size' is the length of the vector to create. In the `rbinom` function, `n` is the length of the vector to create, while `size` is the number of items to hypothetically draw from a theoretical urn having a distribution determined by 'prob'. The result returned is the number of "ones". Try:

```
rbinom(length(x), size = 10, prob=x)
```

Regarding the argument to `prob`: I don't think you need the `c()`.

Comment: I think that the size argument is the doing the same thing in rbinom() as it is in sample().  I believe the difference is that the sample() function gives the raw "trials", whereas the rbinom() function takes it a step further and runs the experiment counting the number of successes in each "trial" as many times as the user specifies.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two function is quite simple.

Think of a pack of shuffled cards, and choose a number of cards from it. That is exactly the situation that `sample` simulates. 
This code,

```
> set.seed(123)
> sample(1:40, 5)
[1] 12 31 16 33 34
```

randomly extract five numbers from the `1:40` vector of numbers.

In your example, you set `size = 1`. It means you choose only one element from the pool of possible values. If you set `size = 10` you will get ten values as you desire.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10, 0, .5)
> sample(rep(c(0,1), length(x)), size = 10, prob = c(rbind(1-x,x)), replace = F)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

Instead, the goal of the `rbinom` function is to simulate events where the results are "discrete", such as the flip of a coin. It considers, as parameters, the probability of success on a trial, such as the flip of the coin, according to a given probability of 0.5. Here we simulate 100 flips. If you think that the coin could be stacked in order to favor one specific outcome, we could simulate this behaviour by setting probability equals to 0.8, as in the example below.

```
> set.seed(123)
> table(rbinom(100, 1, prob = 0.5))
 0  1 
53 47 

> table(rbinom(100, 1, prob = 0.8))
 0  1 
19 81
```

Comment: Worice: That was a typo. It should have read size=10 (since edited). That does give me 10 numbers but when I run a simulation a few thousand times I was getting results that were not consistent with what I was expecting. They were consistently too high (way too many 1's for what probabilities would dictate), which is what led me to find an 'rbhinom' solution.

Comment: I did not get the problem adequately then. Sorry for the misunderstanding!